# Normalize addresses feature - API?

Tags: here-api

Which is the most suitable API for normalizing addresses? I can't find the one that best meets our need.

On Siebel CRM we create addresses and we want to normalize with Here and return the suggestions and choose the most accurate. Is this feature available?

Comment: Why not use the onebox search and just let the backend services handle the search suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the format of address in your CRM and format what you want to get from HERE API?

Comment: The format is quite complex:
We have 
Street Name
Number
Block
Floor
City
County
Country
Postal Code

The aproach will be a web service.

Comment: Did you try to use Geocoding API https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/overview.html for this? It's probably that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) provides a street address validation and standardization/normalization service. They even have an API for autocomplete. You can try it out for free to see if that will suit your needs. I am a software developer for SmartyStreets and helped write many of their SDKs, which may also be of use to you.